# Port forwarding & server: age of empires 2

Tags: port-forwarding

I'm trying to build my own server for AoE 2 + conqueros. I thought that I can simple give to others my public IP address and forward port on router. My PC will so start working as a real server and users can simply connect to me using my public ip address and requests will redirect to my local ip. I read that AoE 2 needs port 2300-2400, 23978, 47624. I also have to add exception on windows firewall. Forwarding ports is the only thing I need to do or should I anyway use hamachi? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It should be working with port following. Note that You will need to forward both `TCP` and `UDP` ports:

```
Initial TCP Connection 47624 Outgoing 47624 Incoming 
Subsequent TCP Incoming 2300-2400 2300-2400 
Subsequent TCP Outgoing 2300-2400 2300-2400 
Subsequent UDP Incoming 2300-2400 2300-2400 
Subsequent UDP Outgoing 2300-2400 2300-2400
```

If you use the Player Matchmaking feature that is provided by GameSpy to find other players, you must also have the ports for the GameSpy Arcade client open.

```
 6667 (IRC) 
 3783 (Voice Chat Port) 
 27900 (Master Server UDP Heartbeat) 
 28900 (Master Server List Request) 
 29900 (GP Connection Manager) 
 29901 (GP Search Manager) 
 13139 (Custom UDP Pings) 
 6515 (Dplay UDP) 
 6500 (Query Port)
```

You should ask a friend to help you troubleshooting.
If you friend can not connect to your server after forwarding these ports, try to completely disable your Windows firewall temporally. If it will work after disabling it, leave a comment and I will update my answer with the firewall settings.

EDIT:

According to steam forum, the Age of Empires II: **HD Edition** edition uses the following ports:

```
UDP 27000 to 27015 inclusive
UDP 27015 to 27030 inclusive
UDP 4380
UDP 3478 (Outbound)
UDP 4379 (Outbound)
```

https://steamcommunity.com/app/221380/discussions/2/828935361235943414/

You should also try to create the server by connecting directly to the internet with your PC so you can determine whether it is not working because of the router is misconfigured or it is blocked by your firewall and/or other local problems.

Comment: Thank you sir. DirectX is strictly needed? Can I choose "All" as type of connection for both TCP and UDP and create only one rule that starts at 2300 and end  at 2400? Thank you again sir, I ' ll test and leave again a comment.

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli - It depends what operating system are you using. Without DirectX you will not be able to play the game. Yes you can use "All" as type. And you can also create a rule for a port range. Feel confident to ask if you have any troubles.

Comment: Thank you. I'm currently installing AoE 2 HD Edition, which includes AoE 2 and The Conquerors. This version is more stable on Windows 7.Do you know if those ports are correct for this version?

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli - is it working?

Comment: Sir, I did port forwarding, started a match with TCP/IP DirectPlay, but my friends can't connect to me. Windows firewall is off. If another local user tries to connect with directplay using local lan as IP, he can join my game.

Comment: @AndreaMartinelli - updated my answer. Please give a feedback after your tried the new configurations

Comment: Didn't work. I don't know exactly what to do. Now I'm using GameRanger. But how does it works? It seems to connect to mi public ip as I said